# How to run Swift Terminal app on another Mac

Tags: xcode, macos, terminal, swift4

This is my first Swift app. Most of my coding experience is in C++ and C#, but I’m fairly new at programming.

I made a Terminal app, called PhotoSorter, using Swift. After building it, I pulled the executable out of the product folder in Xcode and ran it. It works great on my own laptop, but when I try to run the executable on another Mac, I get the following error:

“The alias ‘PhotoSorter’ can’t be opened because the original item can’t be found.”

Question: How are you supposed to create a Swift executable in Xcode that can be ran on any other Mac? Ideally, I want something that the end-user can just right-click/double-click to open.

Comment: Actually copy the file instead of making an alias?

Comment: This is the file that comes out of the product folder.

Comment: You are probably making an alias of it, rather than actually copying. Use the `cp` command in the Terminal, or hold down the Option key if you're dragging it via the mouse.

Comment: And what you actually did was create an alias to the file in the Release folder, instead of actually making a copy. Think of a shortcut on Windows—an alias is like that. On your machine, it points to the file in your Release folder, and that's what gets opened when you double-click it. On another machine, that original file isn't there. The solution is to copy the file instead of making an alias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your question again, I see you're using Xcode. In that case, the best way to distribute your program is to choose "Archive" from the "Product" menu, and when your app is done building, click the "Distribute App" button in the window that appears. Then you can choose your code signature and create a code-signed version of your app (or distribute via the App Store if you're into that sort of thing).

The immediate answer to your question, though, is that you're making an alias instead of copying the file. I assume you've used the mouse to drag and drop out of Xcode's "Products" pseudo-folder. The default action when you do that is to make an alias (which is like a shortcut on Windows). You can override that by holding down the Option key while you drag, but it's better to go the Archive route.

Comment: Your tip worked. Thank you! I tried looking this up before asking the question, but I was having a hard time finding anything.